# VBA Code That Sorts Data Seems to Be Suddenly Ignoring Some Columns/Cells

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2016

I have a sheet that has data in columns `A2:Q and U2:AC`. Both of these ranges have hundreds of rows of data. I have code that sorts this data according to columns `C` and `V`.

Each row contains an identification number and information about a company. However, it appears that some columns within the ranges are not being sorted, so after sorting, these columns values do not align with the company/ID number they were originally aligned with.

E.G. If row 5 has an ID of `10456`, the name `"tomato"` and an opening date of `January 10`, on sorting, the columns with the name and ID would be sorted while the column with the opening date does not move, so it no longer matches the correct ID and name.

Here is my code:

```
With ActiveSheet.Sort
    Range("A2").Sort Key1:=Range("C2"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
    .Apply
End With

With ActiveSheet.Sort
    Range("U2").Sort Key1:=Range("V2"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
    .Apply
End With
```

I have used this code with three data sets with no issue (all columns and data was sorted correctly) but am now running into this issue.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem with the information you have provided.  I suggest you read the HELP pages for information as to [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and then edit your question to provide information so others can better help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to name the full range you want to sort:

```
Private Sub SortMyRanges()
    Dim lastRow As Long
    With ActiveSheet
        lastRow = .UsedRange.Row + .UsedRange.Rows.Count - 1

        .Range("A2:Q" & lastRow).Sort _
            Key1:=.Range("C2"), _
            Order1:=xlAscending, _
            Header:=xlYes, _
            Orientation:=xlTopToBottom

        .Range("U2:AC" & lastRow).Sort _
            Key1:=.Range("V2"), _
            Order1:=xlAscending, _
            Header:=xlYes, _
             Orientation:=xlTopToBottom

    End With
End Sub
```